# Updating the cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I want an application so that when I double click on some cell, the UserForm should pop out, and then there are two TextBoxes where I can type in the title of the problem and the description of it. After typing the problem and description and clicking on a SaveButton, I want the title of the problem to be displayed and somehow pointed out in the entire cell that I initially selected.

For now, when I double click on the cell, the UserForm pops out as it should. However, when I type the title and description of the problem and click "save" then UserForm keeps opening and I cannot close it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim Calrange As Range

    Dim Cell As Range

    Set Calrange = Range("A4:G12")

    Cancel = True

    For Each Cell In Calrange




            task_form.Show



    Next

End Sub
```

And the code inside the UserForm for the SaveButton:

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click()


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False





                ActiveCell.Value = Me.title.Value
                ActiveCell.Value = Me.description_problem.Value

Unload task_form

End Sub
```

Also, I have a dynamic number of worksheets. For now, I paste the code below inside the worksheet that is currently open. However, I do not know initially how many worksheets there are going to be. In the image, I paste my code inside "Sheet1", however, when I execute my code there can be created ten worksheets and I want this function to be working for each of them.

[image]

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)



           Dim Calrange As Range
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Where is `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`? You need to turn it on again...

Comment: @DirkReichel Sorry, i added it without knowing what it is. I'm new in VBA. I deleted it, since as i think it was not influencing the functionality at all.

Comment: Application.ScreenUpdating sets whether Excel will update (redraw) the screen or not. It will speed up your code significantly if you disable this before you write to lots of cells in a macro, but you need to reenable it afterwards, otherwise the screen will behave in strange ways for users.

Comment: Application.ScreenUpdating only remain off for as long as the Sub runs - it will switch back automatically.

Comment: ... which is not meant to imply it's not good practice to explicitly set it back in your code ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Userforms are tricky.

The best way to handle this is to use `task_form.hide` rather than `unload task_form`, then unload it after the `task_form.Show`. Doing it this way means you don't have to rely on `ActiveCell`, you can use Target from the doubleclick event like this:

```
task_form.Show
Target.Value = Me.title.Value
Target.Value = Me.description_problem.Value
unload task_form
```

This will mean that Target.Value is being set as the title value, then being overwritten with the description_problem value, and I don't think you want that.

This way may be better:

```
task_form.Show
Target.Value = Me.title.Value & vblf & Me.description_problem.Value
unload task_form
```

`vblf` inserts a carrage return between the two statements.

To answer your other question about moving code between worksheets, if you right click on a worksheet, and copy it that way, the code also gets copied, so you could set up a template worksheet with the code in place and copy that when needed.

Alternatively, you could use a workbook level event, which will capture any doubleclick on any worksheet:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

This is in the "ThisWorkbook" module. Bear in mind that this will run after worksheet level code, so have your code in either the worksheet modules, or the workbook module, but not both.

Hope this helps!